# UINavigationBar transparent background color issue

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationbar, transparent

I have some problem using a transparent background on UINavigationBar, I get always a black gradient...
This is my code:

```
self.tableView = [[TableController_iPad alloc] initWithNibName:@"TableController_iPad" bundle:nil];

UINavigationController *navi = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.tableView];
[navi.navigationBar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[navi.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[navi.navigationBar setTranslucent:YES];
[navi.navigationBar setOpaque:YES];
[navi.navigationBar setShadowImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"trasparent.png"]];
[navi.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"trasparent.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];


[self addChildViewController:navi];

[viewTesti addSubview:navi.view];
```

Comment: Have you tried to set 'opaque' property to NO instead of YES yet? Like *[navi.navigationBar setOpaque:NO];*

Comment: yes but nothing change!